# Drools FromNodeLeftTuple cannot be cast to ReactiveFromNodeLeftTuple

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine

I was wondering if someone could give me advice. I am getting an exception below when trying to modify a property of a reactive model object from `Java` code.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.drools.core.reteoo.FromNodeLeftTuple cannot be cast to org.drools.core.reteoo.ReactiveFromNodeLeftTuple
at org.drools.core.phreak.ReactiveObjectUtil.notifyModification(ReactiveObjectUtil.java:47)
at org.drools.core.phreak.ReactiveObjectUtil.notifyModification(ReactiveObjectUtil.java:42)
at org.drools.core.phreak.AbstractReactiveObject.notifyModification(AbstractReactiveObject.java:41)
at org.drools.compiler.oopath.model.Person.setAge(Person.java:50)
at org.drools.compiler.oopath.OOPathReactiveTests.testSetter2Rules(OOPathReactiveTests.java:127)
```

I created the following tests to reproduce the problem, the code can be inserted into `org.drools.compiler.oopath.OOPathReactiveTests` in `drools-compiler module in 7.1.0-SNAPSHOT`.

It does not happen when there is only *1 rule* (see `testSetter1Rule()`), it happens with more rules (`testSetter2Rules()`).

```
public class OOPathReactiveTests {

@Test
public void testSetter1Rule() {
    String header =
        "import org.drools.compiler.oopath.model.*;\n" +
            "global java.util.List list\n\n";

    String drl1 =
        "rule R1 when\n" +
            "  Man( $m: /wife[age == 25] )\n" +
            "then\n" +
            "  list.add($m.getName());\n" +
            "end\n\n";

    final KieSession ksession = new KieHelper()
        .addContent( header + drl1, ResourceType.DRL )
        .build()
        .newKieSession();

    final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    ksession.setGlobal( "list", list );

    final Man bob = new Man("John", 25);
    bob.setWife( new Woman("Jane", 25) );

    ksession.insert( bob );
    ksession.fireAllRules();

    bob.getWife().setAge(26);
    ksession.fireAllRules();

    Assertions.assertThat(list).containsExactlyInAnyOrder("Jane");
}

@Test
public void testSetter2Rules() {
    String header =
        "import org.drools.compiler.oopath.model.*;\n" +
            "global java.util.List list\n\n";

    String drl1 =
        "rule R1 when\n" +
            "  Man( $m: /wife[age == 25] )\n" +
            "then\n" +
            "  list.add($m.getName());\n" +
            "end\n\n";

    String drl2 =
        "rule R2 when\n" +
            "  Man( $m: /wife[age == 26] )\n" +
            "then\n" +
            "  list.add($m.getName());\n" +
            "end\n\n";

    final KieSession ksession = new KieHelper()
        .addContent( header + drl1 + drl2, ResourceType.DRL )
        .build()
        .newKieSession();

    final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    ksession.setGlobal( "list", list );

    final Man bob = new Man("John", 25);
    bob.setWife( new Woman("Jane", 25) );

    ksession.insert( bob );
    ksession.fireAllRules();

    bob.getWife().setAge(26);
    ksession.fireAllRules();

    Assertions.assertThat(list).containsExactlyInAnyOrder("Jane", "Jane");
}
```

Jane's `leftTuples` in the moment of the exception are:

```
leftTuples = {HashSet@3461}  size = 2
 0 = {FromNodeLeftTuple@3463} "[fact 0:1:1288815068:1288815068:1:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.drools.compiler.oopath.model.Man:John]"
 1 = {ReactiveFromNodeLeftTuple@3469} "[fact 0:1:1288815068:1288815068:1:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.drools.compiler.oopath.model.Man:John]"
```

I wonder if this is a bug or I am using it wrong way.
Thank you very much.

Peter

Comment: Some x.y-Snapshot is a version taken from ongoing development. It would be better if you post your finding on some Drools mailing list.

Comment: @laune Thank you, I did.

Comment: The issue is fixed in https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-1589

Answer (score 0):

After posting the problem to https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!forum/drools-usage

it has been fixed very quickly by drools developers in https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-1589